# Load email from quote or order or billing address?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

What is the correct structure to load the email of the customer from? It should work in all order variants: orders by guests, orders by registrered customers, already saved addresses, newly entered addresses in checkout process.

Background:
I'm investigating an issue with a payment extension. I turned out that sometimes the extension doesn't have an email address for the customer.

We found that the extension loads the email address for order processing the following way:

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()
```

Testing in stock **magento 1.7.0.2 with sample data** showed that the email address is not saved into the billing address **if**

1. customer creates an account (just name, email, password, no addresses)
2. customer loads cart and starts checkout with entering billing/shipping address.

In this case billing/shipping address don't have email set and the extension fails.
You can confirm this by looking at the tables

- sales_flat_quote
- sales_flat_quote_address

during order.

There are more places to load the email from:

```
$order->getCustomer()->getEmail()
$order->getCustomerEmail()
$quote->getCustomerEmail()
```

So what is the correct structure to load the email from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the stage you need the address.  If the order is not completed you'd better use `$quote` object instead of the `$order` object.  Like

```
$email = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
if (!$email) $email = $quote->getCustomerEmail();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I settled for this code. Although i use empty for variable checking:
`if (empty($email)) $email = $quote->getCustomerEmail();`
I filed a bug for the payment extension which brought me to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
$order->getCustomer()->getEmail()
```

is the safest since all the orders have a customer associated, even if its a guest. The 2 cases you pointed should be covered too with this approach.